# Multiple `subplot2grid` in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot two different sets of functions going once through a double loop. I don't know how I can ask subplot2grid to act on the second figure.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
t=np.linspace(0,1,100)
fig1=plt.figure()
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(i,j))
        plt.plot(t,np.sin((t*np.random.random()*10)))
fig2=plt.figure()
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(i,j))
        plt.plot(t,np.cos((t*np.random.random()*10)))
plt.show()
```

Is there any way to do this with only one loop?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the object-oriented interface. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(3, 3)
fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(3, 3)

blue, red = "#1E90FF", "#FF6347"
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        axes1[i, j].plot(t, np.sin((t * np.random.random() * 10)), blue)
        axes2[i, j].plot(t, np.cos((t * np.random.random() * 10)), red)

fig1.tight_layout()
fig2.tight_layout()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I was hoping that more attractive images would yield me additional internet points.