# Subplot2grid in a for loop

Tags: matplotlib

I want to use subplot2grid in a for loop, but can't seem to attach imshow to a loop variable:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,8), (0,0), colspan=4, rowspan=2) 
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,8), (2,0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((6,8), (0,4), colspan=6, rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((6,8), (2,4), colspan=6, rowspan=2)
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((6,8), (4,0), colspan=4, rowspan=2)

galaxies= [...]
a=[ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5]

for i in range(0,5):
  image = mpimg.imread(galaxies[i]+'_CombinedHistogram.png')
  a[i].imshow(image)

plt.show()
```

In this line:

```
a[i].imshow(image)
```

I get the following error message: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing.

I have seen this answer: [Multiple `subplot2grid` in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896813/multiple-subplot2grid-in-a-for-loop), but is there absolutely no way to use subplot2grid and the 'axes' object in a for loop? I feel like I am missing something. Thanks for any clarification!

EDIT: code

Comment: you really shouldn't change your question in an edit. You have a new question now you previous one is fixed, so ask a new question

Comment: also, your (updated) code works fine for me. Are you sure you are using `a[i].imshow` and not trying to index one of your `Axes` objects?

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the items in `a` to strings, not the axes objects you created.

Change

```
a=['ax1', 'ax2', 'ax2', 'ax4', 'ax5']
```

to

```
a=[ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5]
```

(there was also a typo where you used `ax2` twice, an no `ax3`)