# Having two subplot2grid inside a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib

I looked at this solution:
[Multiple `subplot2grid` in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896813/multiple-subplot2grid-in-a-for-loop)
, but it was unfortunately not working for me!

So I am using the following code in order to produce plots:

```
stations = ["A", "B", "C"]
variables = ["d", "e", "f"]
for i, variable in enumerate(variables):
    fig = plt.figure(0)
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (i,0))
    for j, station in enumerate(stations):
        fig1 = plt.figure(1)
        ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,3),(0,j))
        plt.bar(A)
        plt.bar(B)
        plt.bar(C)
    plt.savefig(1.pdf)
    plt.close()
plt.savefig(2.pdf)
plt.close()
```

But this code is just producing the plot inside the second loop (`fig1`).
And the plots of the first loop are just empty pdf (`fig`).

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you saying your 2.pdf is completely empty? As in, it doesn't even have a figure with no data plotted?

Comment: I don't understand what the desired output is supposed to be?

Comment: The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896813/multiple-subplot2grid-in-a-for-loop you referred to recommends to use the object oriented interface of matplotlib. So instead of calling `plt.bar`, call `ax.bar` with the axis object you want the plot to appear on.